# mysql statement wont insert

Tags: mysql, insert, unique-values, insert-statement

Hey guys I've searched for answers through the forums but to no avail so I'm using MySql and I'm trying to insert statements for certain tables and they aren't going into the tables and I'm getting errors like "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."
These are the statements I'm having problems with.`INSERT INTO Course VALUES

```
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (12345, 'DatabaseManagement', '2015-2-1', '2014-5-9');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (12346, 'Calculus', '2015-1-12', '2015-5-9');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (12347, 'Biology', '2015-1-3', '2015-5-9');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (12348, 'Chemistry', '2015-1-2', '2015-5-9');

INSERT INTO Grade VALUES (10, 12345, 012, 'A');
INSERT INTO Grade VALUES (11, 12346, 013, 'B');
INSERT INTO Grade VALUES (12, 12347, 014, 'C');
INSERT INTO Grade VALUES (13, 12348, 015, 'D');
INSERT INTO Grade VALUES (14, 12345, 016, 'B');

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (54321, 'Rachel', 'Cotterel', '2013-4-15', '2016-3-4');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (54320, 'John', 'Smith', '2012-1-23', NULL);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (54319, 'Johny', 'Depp', '2010-5-12', '2012-10-10');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (54318, 'Orlando', 'Bloom', '2014-6-24', NULL);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (54317, 'Linda', 'Jacob', '2015-4-4', '2019-8-6');
```

Comment: What do your Course, Student and Grade tables look like? What fields and data types do they have?

Comment: Cant reproduce http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff12 There were other errors though,the foreign key in grades didint match a  courseID and all of the studentIds were wrong

Comment: That is a SQL Server error, not a MySQL error. Please verify whether you are actually using MySQL.

Comment: Your right Andriy I'm using SQL Server, my apology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any error for insert into Course statements. I got error for  INSERT INTO Grade statements. Its because there is no reference available for StudentID 012,013 etc in Student table. And you are trying to add them in grade table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the field types:

```
CREATE TABLE Course
(
CourseID int,
Description varchar(20) NOT NULL,
StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_CourseID] PRIMARY KEY (CourseID)
);  

CREATE TABLE Grade
(
GradeID integer(10) NOT NULL,
CourseID integer(10) NOT NULL,
StudentID integer(10) NOT NULL,
Grade varchar (10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_GradeID] PRIMARY KEY (GradeID),
CONSTRAINT [FK_CourseID] FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES Course(CourseID),
CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentID] FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID)
);

CREATE TABLE Student
(
StudentID integer(10) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(45) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(45) NOT NULL,
RegistrationDate varchar (45) NOT NULL,
GraduationDate DATE NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentlID] PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

String or binary data would be truncated
The reason that you get this message should be that you are trying to insert some value to some field to which you haven't assigned enough size to hold the value.
Can you send what the exact error message you get?

I tried to do it myself.But the error I got was from you insertion query to Grade table foreign key fails which refer Student table because you are trying to insert Student_IDs which are not there in you Student table